# probelm at installing channels(django), and importing it's inner packages(channels.layout)

Tags: python, django, pip, django-channels, channel

I have the same problem.
pyhton(3.9.1).
using virtual environmnet (venv).
installed django.
updated:
setuptools: pip install --upgrade setuptools,
pip(20.3.3): py -m pip install --upgrade pip
wheel: python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
(latesed version for today(30/12/20)).

Tried to use: python -m pip install -U channels.
installed "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools"

Tried the self installing twisted: [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#twisted)

All done, but still not working.

Also tried pip install:
pip install pytype
pip install django-channels.

The django-channels, but when runnig on PyCharm, it recognize channels but not: channels.layers.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Most probably because the python installation you installed `channels` to and the one Pycharm uses are different. In Pycharm, write somewhere `import sys; print(sys.executable)`, run the script. In terminal, write `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` and compare the output.

Comment: The first problem, is that im not able to complete the installation of channels.
It fails on:  'Building wheel for twisted (setup.py): started'

The second problem is even when im trying to install django-channels, however this package not including:
channels.layers,
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer

Answer (score 1):

I managed to install it:
just removed python, and installed instead Anaconda 3.